# calculate daydifference between 2 date fields in a table

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, delphi-xe

I can't seem to make this work in the grid:

```
procedure TForm1.ABSQuery1CalcFields(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
// if (ABSQuery1.FieldByName('START_DATE').AsDateTime > 0) and (ABSQuery1.FieldByName('END_DATE').AsDateTime > 0) then
//    ABSQuery1.FieldByName('DAYS').AsInteger:= Daysbetween(ABSQuery1.FieldByName('START_DATE').AsDateTime,ABSQuery1.FieldByName('END_DATE').AsDateTime)
//else
//    ABSQuery1.FieldByName('DAYS').Value := Null;

end;
```

I have created an extra field in the query (integer type) for the purpose. But it does not work.
I get:

> [dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(64): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'Daysbetween'

Tried this one for short :

```
ABSQuery1.FieldByName('DAYS').Value := 
   IntToStr( 
      Daysbetween(ABSQuery1.FieldByName('START_DATE').AsDateTime, 
                  ABSQuery1.FieldByName('END_DATE').AsDateTime)
   );
```

but still nothing. How do I get this to work ?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `System.DateUtils` unit into your uses clause. Whenever you'll be missing a certain function identifier, take a look at the function's reference. In your case the [`DaysBetween`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.DateUtils.DaysBetween) function help shows as the source of this function the `System.DateUtils` unit, which you're missing:

```
uses
  System.DateUtils;
```

Here is highlighted, how to identify the missing unit:

[image]

Comment: I forgot about the damn dateutils... :)Thank you !